# haskell - types - functions - trees

Tags: haskell, types, tree

For haskell practice I want to implement a game where students/pupils should learn some algebra playfully.

As basic datatype I want to use a tree:

- with nodes that have labels and algebraic operators stored.
- with leaves that have labels and variables (type String) or numbers

Now I want to define something like

```
data Tree = Leaf {l :: Label, val :: Expression}
          | Node {l :: Label, f :: Fun, lBranch :: Tree, rBranch :: Tree}

data Fun = "one of [(+),(*),(-),(/),(^)]"

-- type Fun = Int -> Int
```

would work

Next things I think about is to make a 'equivalence' of trees - as multiplication/addition is commutative and one can simplify additions to multiplication etc. the whole bunch of algebraic operations.
I also have to search through the tree - by label I think is best, is this a good approach.

Any ideas what tags/phrases to look for and how to solve the "data Fun".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand a bit on Edward Z. Yang's answer:

The simplest way to define your operators here is probably as a data type, along with the types for atomic values in leaf nodes and the expression tree as a whole:

```
data Fun = Add | Mul | Sub | Div | Exp deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data Val a = Lit a | Var String deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data ExprTree a = Node String Fun (ExprTree a) (ExprTree a)
                | Leaf String (Val a)
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

You can then define `ExprTree a` as an instance of `Num` and whatnot:

```
instance (Num a) => Num (ExprTree a) where
    (+) = Node "" Add
    (*) = Node "" Mul
    (-) = Node "" Sub
    negate = Node "" Sub 0
    fromInteger = Leaf "" . Lit
```

...which allows creating unlabelled expressions in a very natural way:

```
*Main> :t 2 + 2
2 + 2 :: (Num t) => t
*Main> 2 + 2 :: ExprTree Int
Node "" Add (Leaf "" (Lit 2)) (Leaf "" (Lit 2))
```

Also, note the `deriving` clauses above on the data definitions, particularly `Ord`; this tells the compiler to automatically create an ordering relation on values of that type. This lets you sort them consistently which means you can, for instance, define a canonical ordering on subexpressions so that when rearranging commutative operations you don't get stuck in a loop. Given some canonical reductions and subexpressions in canonical order, in most cases you'll then be able to use the automatic equality relation given by `Eq` to check for subexpression equivalence.

Note that labels will affect the ordering and equality here. If that's not desired, you'll need to write your own definitions for `Eq` and `Ord`, much like the one I gave for `Num`.

After that, you can write some traversal and reduction functions, to do things like apply operators, perform variable substitution, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to construct a *symbolic algebra system.* There is a large and varied literature on the subject.

You don't want to represent operators as `Int -> Int`, because then you can't check what operation any given function implements and then implement peephole optimization for things like simplification, etc. So a simple enumerated data type would do the trick, and then write the function `eval` which actually evaluates your tree.